# Stripping duplicate words from generated text in python script

Tags: python, string, text, duplicates

I made a python script to take text from an input file and randomly rearrange the words for a creative writing project based around the cut-up technique (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-up_technique).

Here's the script as it currently stands. NB: I'm running this as a server side include.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from random import shuffle 

src = open("input.txt", "r")
srcText = src.read()
src.close()

srcList = srcText.split()
shuffle(srcList)
cutUpText = " ".join(srcList)
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n" + cutUpText)
```

This basically does the job I want it to do, but one improvement I'd like to make is to identify duplicate words within the output and remove them. To clarify, I only want to identify duplicates in a sequence, for example "the the" or "I I I". I don't want to make it so that, for example, "the" only appears once in the entire output.

Can someone point me in the right direction to start solving this problem? (My background isn't in programming at all, so I basically put this script together through a lot of reading bits of the python manual and browsing this site. Please be gentle with me.)

Comment: Do you mind sharing you code in public-domain on Wikipedia? You don't have to.

Comment: Of course not! Feel free to do whatever you like with it.

Comment: As an amateur writer of sorts, I appreciate the problem from 'creative writing' angle; SO can be educational, or what. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I saw your version of the script on Wikipedia. Thanks so much for that, I'm super-flattered that the script I cobbled together in ignorance could be used to make something more appropraite for mass consumption like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a generator to produce words without duplicates:

```
def nodups(s):
    last = None
    for w in s:
        if w == last:
            continue
        yield w
        last = w
```

Then you can use this in your program:

```
cutUpText = " ".join(nodups(srcList))
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks very much, I wasn't expecting a full example, just a bit of guidance.
(I got around this being case-sensitive by dropping the input to lowercase earlier in the script, as it's designed to go in all lowercase anyway to avoid having words capitalised randomly in the middle of a sentence.)

Comment: I find that you have to 'sort' the list, and call the nodups() generator, especially before the 'shuffle' bit to effectively eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: @Arcturus: you must have a different need than kultur.  He simply doesn't want repeated words in a row, but is ok with repeats somewhere in the text.

Comment: Sure; it is indeed a very relevant example of using generators - better than any texts I've read up on.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the lines

```
spaces = [(i%10) == 9 and '\n' or ' ' for i in range(0,len(srcList))];
cutUpText = "".join(map(lambda x,y: "".join([x,y]),srcList,spaces));
```

helps bring some raw formatting to the text screens.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your existing program:

```
srcList = list(set(srcText.split()))
```